# What is the right syntax in this example?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, sql-insert

I have had this question for school but can't figure out why it is wrong. My teacher tells me the syntax should be different from what I wrote. The code still runs but I can't find any official websites to prove it is still acceptable.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION oepsie()
RETURNS trigger
LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$
DECLARE
    is_allergic uuid;
BEGIN
    SELECT allergy FROM drugallergy into is_allergic WHERE NEW.drug = drugallergy.allergy AND NEW.patient = drugallergy.patient;
    IF is_allergic IS NOT NULL THEN
        RAISE NOTICE 'PATIENT ALLERGIC';
    RETURN NULL;
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER t_allergy_prescription
    BEFORE INSERT ON prescription
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE oepsie();
```

Above is my own code which worked on my laptop just fine. It should desplay an error when inserting into the prescription table with the wrong values.

```
SELECT into is_allergic allergy FROM drugallergy WHERE NEW.drug = drugallergy.allergy AND NEW.patient = drugallergy.patient;
```

But my professor tells me the into has to go before the from statement. Am I in the wrong? And if not, where can I find evidence that it's okay to use my way?

Comment: The [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-selectinto.html) show the `INTO` always being before the `FROM`

Comment: This function raises no error, and your query will not find the row that you are about to insert (because it is not inserted yet). I cannot say more, because I don't understand what exactly the trigger should achieve. "Wrong values" is not exactly a precise description...

Comment: Read the docs [Select Into](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW).

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I'm sorry for the discription I gave but I wil try to explain it as best as I can. When a value is inserted into the prescription table the trigger happens and checks to see if 2 values are the same (a patient is allergic if these 2 values are the same, this was what I meant with wrong values). If this is true then an error is raised and the values won't be added to the prescription table. If this is false it wil insert the values into the prescription table. I hope this cleares things up a little.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Thanks for your response. I have just read the docs again and came upon the same explanation: "The INTO clause can appear almost anywhere in the SQL command. Customarily it is written either just before or just after the list of select_expressions in a SELECT command, or at the end of the command for other command types. It is recommended that you follow this convention in case the PL/pgSQL parser becomes stricter in future versions." Does this mean it is accepted to do a FROM clause before a INTO clause? I'm quite new to sql so I apologise if it is an obvious answer

Comment: 1) As pointed out above  `SELECT ... INTO` in `plpgsql` is different from SQL [SELECT INTO](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-selectinto.html). 2) Yes you can put the `INTO` in the `plgsql` version after the `FROM`. 3) The docs hint at this changing, but they have been saying that for at least 20 years now. I don't see it happening as it would break too much code.

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW) says:

> The `INTO` clause can appear almost anywhere in the SQL command. Customarily it is written either just before or just after the list of `select_expressions` in a `SELECT` command, or at the end of the command for other command types. It is recommended that you follow this convention in case the PL/pgSQL parser becomes stricter in future versions.

So technically you are right.  If your professor claims that your code is illegal PL/pgSQL syntax, he or she is wrong.  If is is a question of style rather than of correctness, I'd agree that it would be better to write the `INTO` clause right after the `SELECT` list.